# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'item_name' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get rid of this error my friend and I have been having issues with. The error is in the title and happens at line 93... any ideas or suggestions? Line 93 is marked with a comment below. `document.body.innerHTML.replace("__ITEM__", pocket.item_name); //LINE 93`

Another thing I'd like to mention is that I've cropped out all unnecessary code (I think) so please do ask if you need another section.

I won't be surprised if this is some newbie mistake, so feel free to call me out on it. I also apologise for any bad practices or such you may find, I am still new to this.

The function **start()** is called first.

```
var status, items_none, items, pocket, money;

function item(item_name, usage_id, description, minimum_cost) {
    this.item_name = item_name;
    this.usage_id = usage_id;
    this.description = description;
    this.worth = minimum_cost;
    this.usage_verb = "Use";
    this.choose_number = false;
}    
function start() {
    status = "Welcome to Collector.";

    items_none = item("---", -2, "Your pockets are empty.", 0);
    items = new Array();
    items[0] = item("Cardboard Box", 0, "Open the box to see what's inside.", 100);
    ...

    pocket = items_none; //Start with empty pockets.
    money = 100; //Start with 0 coins.

    updateGui();
}
function updateGui() {
    //This updates all text on the page.
    document.body.innerHTML.replace("__COINS__", money);
    document.body.innerHTML.replace("__ITEM__", pocket.item_name); //LINE 93
    document.body.innerHTML.replace("__STATUS__", status);
    document.body.innerHTML.replace("__ITEM:USE__", pocket.usage_verb);
    document.body.innerHTML.replace("__ITEM:DESC__", pocket.description);
    document.body.innerHTML.replace("__ITEM:WORTH__", pocket.worth);
    document.body.innerHTML.replace("__ITEM:VERB__", pocket.usage_verb);
}
```

Like always, thanks in advance and happy coding!

Comment: Which line is line 93?  There aren't 93 lines in your sample.

Comment: @EricBrown I have marked it with a comment.
`document.body.innerHTML.replace("__ITEM__", pocket.item_name); //LINE 93`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `new` before `item` each time, e.g.

```
items_none = new item("---", -2, "Your pockets are empty.", 0);
...
items[0] = new item("Cardboard Box", 0, "Open the box to see what's inside.", 100);
```

Why is this? Consider a function called `pair`:

```
function pair(x, y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
```

Just calling it without `new` means you are making a simple function call. `this` just refers the current object context, which is probably `window`.

```
p = pair(55, 66);
alert(window.x == 55); // true!
alert(p.x); // error--p is undefined.
```

'new' expects a function and treats it as a constructor. `this` is set to the new object.

```
p = new pair(55, 66);
alert(window.x == 55); // false!
alert(p.x); // 55!
```

Comment: Agh, knew this would be one of those dumb mistakes. Thanks, appreciate it! +1 for you as well as accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation. Really helps!